# clEnqueueFillBuffer fails to fill

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have a buffer created device side and I would like to initialise the values inside this buffer. OpenCL 1.2 provides the function clEnqueueFillBuffer (http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueFillBuffer.html) for this type of operation.

Calling this function fails to initialise my memory correctly but does not return any error code to suggest that the function failed.

Here is the code I use:

```
int initGridSize = 64*64*64;    // initial 3D volume size
cl_uint initVoxelValue = 255;   // initial value of each voxel in the volume

// create the buffer on the device
cl_mem buff = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, initGridSize*sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, &err);
if(err < 0) {
    perror("Couldn't create a buffer object");
    exit(1);
}

// Fill the buffer with the initial value
err = clEnqueueFillBuffer(queue, buff, &initVoxelValue, sizeof(cl_uint), 0, initGridSize*sizeof(cl_uint), 0, NULL, NULL);
if(err != CL_SUCCESS) {
    perror("Couldn't fill a buffer object");
    exit(1);
}
clFinish(queue);

// create a host side buffer and read the device side buffer into the host buffer
cl_uint *grid = new cl_uint [ initGridSize ];
err  = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buff, CL_TRUE, 0, initGridSize*sizeof(cl_int), &grid[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    perror("Couldn't read a buffer object");
    exit(1);
}

// print the first 11 values in the buffer
cl_uint *g = grid;
for( int i=0; i<11; i++, g++ )
{
    printf("Voxel %i, %u\n", i, *g );
}
delete [] grid;
```

And the output is this:

```
Voxel 0, 0
Voxel 1, 0
Voxel 2, 0
Voxel 3, 0
Voxel 4, 0
Voxel 5, 0
Voxel 6, 0
Voxel 7, 0
Voxel 8, 0
Voxel 9, 0
Voxel 10, 0
```

It would be simple enough to write a kernel to fill the buffer, but ideally I would like to get this working.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, or is this a driver bug?

Comment: By chance, in your system int is 32bits? Because if it is 16bits, 64*64*64 will result in 4 overflows, and a final result of 0.

Comment: Is your Device OpenCL 1.2 compliant?

Comment: My system is 32 bits, I'm pretty sure it's not overflowing, I've set breakpoints and initGridSize is correct, as is initGridSize*sizeof(cl_uint). I am using a mid 2013 iMac and my system reports that OpenCL 1.2 is fully supported too...

`CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE
CL_PLATFORM_VERSION: OpenCL 1.2 (Apr 25 2014 22:04:25)`

Answer (score 0):

You've set your buffer with the **CL_MEM_READ_ONLY** flag. Set it to **CL_MEM_READ_WRITE** so you can write value in it.